# error in post request to a route in index.js file inside firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

i have craeted a  from in index.html and using it , i am sending a POST  request to an express route written inside firebase cloud functions.

when i deploy the app and  login using that form i am redirected to the route but the page shows " internal server error"

also, if i dont deploy and just serve the functions and go to /home route, it gets rendered.

please help .
thankyou

my index.html login form :

```
 <!--LOGIN -->   
        <div id="login" class="modal">
          <form class="modal-content" method="POST" action="https://samsungmap-17515.web.app/home">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Login</h1>
          <p>Please fill in this form to Login.</p>
          <hr>
          <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email2" required>


          <label for="roll no"><b>Roll NO.</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Roll Number" id="roll2" required>

          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="psw2" required>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('signup').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="signup">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

my index.js file :

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(
    functions.config().firebase
);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const app = express();

app.set('view engine','ejs');
//-------------------------------------------------------------------//

app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("teacher",{bio:"Chahat"});
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error? There must have been some underlying error message, perhaps in the Logs for the "Internal Server error" reported on the Page. Please check the logs and provide the error information reported. Additionally, where is this "https://samsungmap-17515.web.app/home"?

Comment: I have created a form in the index.html file . Also , i have created a home route in the index.js file inside functions folder. Now i want that as the user logs in to the form , a post request is sent and the user redirects to the home route. I changed the action attribute inside form to "action = ./home " .  When the user logs in from frontend i get a msg saying "CANNOT POST TO /HOME" and if i change the url adding the home parameter, it says "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", while no error is shown is the console.

Comment: how to i redirect the user to home route after he logs in through the from ?